# Python Pandas - Merge dataFrame on every item in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have Table 'sales':

```
          ProductId   Sales
0               [1]   $199
1               [2]   $299
2         [3, 4, 5]   $399
3         [6, 7, 8]   $499
```

and Table 'product':

```
        ID            Product
0       1                   A
1       2                   B
2       3                   C
3       4                   D
4       5                   E
5       6                   F
6       7                   G
7       8                   H
```

I want to return a new table 'sales_product'

```
            Product   Sales
0                 A   $199
1                 B   $299
2             C,D,E   $399
3             F,G,H   $499
```

So it can find all the matched `ProductId` and return `Product` value as a comma-joined string in the new table.

Any Python method can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this, create a lookup with `ID` & `Product` then map it back to `sales` dataset.

```
# {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'...}
lookup = product.set_index("ID")['Product'].to_dict()

sales['Product'] = sales.ProductId.apply(
    lambda x: ",".join([lookup[v] for v in x if lookup.get(v)])
)
```

---

```
  Product Sales
0       A  $199
1       B  $299
2   C,D,E  $399
3   F,G,H  $499
```